# Recurring profiles: nominal items lose total in checkout

Tags: onepage-checkout, recurring

I have created a recurring profile for a product in the admin, added it to the cart, and go to the checkout (onepage).

The billing information page shows the nominal item correctly:

[image: billing]

However once I select the billing address and go to the shipping information, the nominal item now has a price of $0.00:

[image: shipping]

There are no payment methods available once I add in the shipping information, which I would assume is because the grand total is $0.00.

Any thoughts? I've looked in the controller to see if there is any nominal-product specific code, but didn't see anything that would reset the price to $0.00.

Comment: afaik you can not mix nominal and standard products. But I can't remember who told me this, or why :-/

Comment: Thanks Fabian - I'm not mixing products. There is only one nominal item in the cart.